# Google Chrome Extension for blocking redirects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Using Chrome Extension, I want to stop a Webpage from redirecting to another page (Different URL). I need to stop the redirects but without displaying any alert message/popups. so when this extension is 'enabled' on google chrome. It will do the work of blocking the re-directs. Once the page loads fully, i.e. all the scripts, HTML are loaded etc only then 'ESC' or stop by default trigger. If not 'ESC' then some other way to stop re-direct without any pop-up or alerts.

As part of this, the example HTML code and my JS code reads:

```js
var seconds = 3; // seconds for HTML
var foo; // variable for clearInterval() function

function redirect() {
    document.location.href = 'http://bubencode.com';
}

function updateSecs() {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    seconds--;
    if (seconds == -1) {
        clearInterval(foo);
        redirect();
    }
}

function countdownTimer() {
    foo = setInterval(function () {
        updateSecs()
    }, 1000);
}

countdownTimer();

window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "Stop";}; //Alert
```

```html
<p>You should be automatically redirected in <span id="seconds">3</span> seconds.
</p>
```

I am facing the following two issues or need help in:

1. `window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "Stop";};` 
   is not working.
2. Is there an alternate way to stop this redirect process with no browser alerts or pop-ups? I have used the following ESC keycode (27) but it also fails:

```js
$(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 27
    $('document').trigger(e);
});
```

I want to implement a chrome extension to automatically take care of this.
I need help in  javascript code. The HTML code mentioned is just for the example.
I'm sorry if the question here is irrelevant. Please excuse me for the same.

Comment: `my Javascript and HTML code reads` - not sure what "my" means here. Is it is what the webpage uses to redirect itself? If so, you'll have to overwrite the entire page code to remove that script ([example](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14164-kinozal-tv-remove-external-scripts/code)).

Comment: No, I am not looking to overwrite the code. Only javascript code I need help in. The HTML code mentioned is just for the example.

Comment: My point is, if the webpage uses a similar approach, and the timer variable `foo` isn't global, overwriting the page is the only solution.